# Signalr for getting when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, signalr

I am using Iframe inside my code, So when iframe is giving some response i cant able to capture the response of that,So what should i try to capture the response inside Iframe,i tried to use signalR but confused.
please help me here once.

Comment: If the contents of the <iframe> are not from the same origin where you are trying to capture the response, the browser will prevent you from doing so for security reasons.

Comment: Earlier i frame is posting the message to me,so by using event listener i am capturing,but now i am not getting any post message from i frame i am getting only small notification inside iframe ,so how to capture?

Comment: We would need to see the code that's causing the problem in order to make a reasonable guess at what the problem is.

Comment: ok. i need to track the response coming inside I frame.

Comment: can you help me how to track the response coming inside Iframe by using React js